# How to pass navigation object to sider panel from navigationOptions in React-Navigation v3?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have some stackNavigator's in which navigationOptions has a headerLeft that refers to the component which returns TouchableOpacity. When I click on it, `siderOpened` parameter will change from `false` to `true` via React Context API.

There is also a Sider component that takes `navigation` object prop, which is always `undefined`. Sider is displayed depending on `useContext(SiderOpenedContext)` which changes from MenuButton component.

```
const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerBackImage: null,
      headerTitle: 'Profile',
      headerLeft: <MenuButton />
    }
  },
  'Profile.Settings': {
    screen: Settings,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerBackImage: null,
      headerTitle: 'Settings',
      headerLeft: <MenuButton />,
    }
  }
})
```

(there are 4 stacks which are identical to this)

```
export const Navigation = createAppContainer(
  createBottomTabNavigator({
    PasswordRecoveryStack: {
      screen: PasswordRecoveryStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        visible: false,
      },
    },
    RegistrationStack: {
      screen: RegistrationStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        visible: false,
      },
    },
    CourtRental: {
      screen: CourtRentalStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: renderIcon(bookingCourt, bookingCourtH),
        title: 'Rentals',
      },
    },
    ProfileStack: {
      screen: ProfileStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: renderIcon(profile, profileH),
        title: 'Profile',
      },
    },
    About: {
      screen: AboutStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: renderIcon(tournaments, tournamentsH),
        title: 'About'
      }
    }
  })
)
```

(all the stacks are united here)

```
const MenuButton = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { siderOpened, setSiderOpened } = useContext(SiderOpenedContext)
  console.log(navigation)
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSiderOpened(!siderOpened)}>
      <Image source={bMenu} resizeMethod="scale" style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 25 }} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

(MenuButton component)

```
const Sider = ({ navigation, opened }) => {
  const { setSiderOpened } = useContext(SiderOpenedContext)

  const items = [
    {
      title: 'Profile',
      onPress: () => { navigation.navigate('Profile') }
    },
    {
      title: 'About',
      onPress: () => { navigation.navigate('About') }
    }
    {
      title: 'Feedback',
      onPress: () => { navigation.navigate('About.Feedback') }
    }
  ]

  return (
    <View style={{ ...styles.root, ...(opened ? styles.rootOpened : {}) }}>
      <View style={styles.top}>
        <Text style={styles.exitBtn} onPress={() => setSiderOpened(false)}>⨯</Text>
      </View>
      <List items={items} />
      <View style={styles.adView}>
        <Text style={styles.desc}>Lorem ipsum dolor</Text>
        <Text style={styles.url} onPress={() => { Linking.openURL('http://example.com') }}>
          Example.com
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

(Sider component. `navigation` object is always `undefined` there)